Cannot convert IAM secret access key to SMTP credentials
I'm trying to convert secret access key to SMTP credentials. I followed instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/smtp-credentials.html and grabbed implementation from https://gist.github.com/damusix/c12400ee0ccb7e56351619ae2b19a303. However when I try to send email, nodemailer throws error: Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid. What am I missing?
const region = "eu-central-1";

const date = "11111111";
const service = "ses";
const terminal = "aws4_request";
const message = "SendRawEmail";
const versionInBytes = [0x04];

function sign(key, msg: string) {
  return crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", Buffer.from(key.map((a) => a.charCodeAt(0))))
    .update(utf8.encode(msg))
    .digest("latin1")
    .split("");
}

export const generateSmtpPassword = (key: string) => {
  let signature = sign(utf8.encode("AWS4" + key).split(""), date);
  signature = sign(signature, region);
  signature = sign(signature, service);
  signature = sign(signature, terminal);
  signature = sign(signature, message);

  const signatureAndVersion = versionInBytes.slice(); //copy of array

  signature.forEach((a) => signatureAndVersion.push(a.charCodeAt(0)));

  const smtpPassword = Buffer.from(signatureAndVersion).toString("base64");

  return smtpPassword;
};

const id = generateId("project");

const iam = await getIAM();

const { User } = await iam.createUser({
  UserName: `project.${id}`,
});

if (!User?.UserName) throw new Error("Failed to create IAM user");

await iam.attachUserPolicy({
  UserName: User.UserName,
  PolicyArn: "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSESFullAccess",
});

const { AccessKey } = await iam.createAccessKey({
  UserName: User.UserName,
});

if (!AccessKey?.AccessKeyId || !AccessKey?.SecretAccessKey)
  throw new Error("AccessKeyId or SecretAccessKey is missing");

const smtpPassword = generateSmtpPassword(AccessKey.SecretAccessKey);

console.log(AccessKey);
//{
//  UserName: 'project.wLhJPIEKdSX3QIEB',
//  AccessKeyId: 'AKIA34AMCYCZNSLPIOGL',
//  Status: 'Active',
//  SecretAccessKey: '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',
//  CreateDate: 2024-10-25T08:41:51.000Z
//}

console.log(smtpPassword);
// BJFVirrONXceMVwlLwSiGPYw2NG1BCRmSlcslY5lg+SC

const transport = createTransport({
  host: "email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: AccessKey.AccessKeyId,
    pass: smtpPassword,
  },
});

await transport.sendMail({
  subject: ...,
  to: "***", // Verified address
  text: ...,
  from: "***", // Verified address
});


So first of all I used this implementation for the conversion: https://gist.github.com/jesusgoku/533ba67ea218608c5a74a6d341d75189. But the reason it didn't work is that AWS needs to propagate the user across their systems (according to ChatGPT). So I've added delay (around 10s) before sending the email. await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000))
